# pgbouncer and ssl connection

Tags: postgresql, ssl, pgbouncer

I have three Servers, two of whom are running postgres 9.5.3 and the third runs pgbouncer 1.7.2.

i can access one of the two postgresql instance through pgbouncer and it all works perfect. the other postgresql Servers, lets call it P1 is not under my control and i have to connect using ssl so it got and therefor the following line was added to this Servers pga_hba.conf

```
hostssl    all       all             ###.###.###.###/32               md5
```

I can connect to P1 from pgbouncer server with psql with no Problem.
But when i connect via pgbouncer to P1 i get this error message

```
psql: ERROR:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", user "myuser", database "mydb", SSL off
```

here is my pgbouncer.ini

```
[databases]
my_database = host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx port=5432 dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypassword client_encoding='UTF8'

[pgbouncer]
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 5432
auth_type = md5 

auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
logfile = /var/log/postgresql/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/postgresql/pgbouncer.pid

admin_users = rms_admin 

pool_mode = session

server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL
server_check_query = select 1

default_pool_size = 40

stats_period=300

log_pooler_errors = 1
```

i've tried add **sslmode=require** on the connection string to my_database in combination with **ignore_startup_parameters** but that led to the following error in the pgbouncer log .

```
ERROR skipping database my_database because of unknown parameter in connstring: sslmode
```

how can i make pgbouncer build up an ssl Connection?

Comment: Did you tried to use auth_file='hba' + auth_hba_file in pgbouncer? Check [HBA file format](https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html).

Comment: my understanding is that auth_hba_file is used for connections from clients to pgbouncer. My problem is the connection between pgbouncer and the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS between pgbouncer and server is not enabled through the connect string, but with `server_tls_sslmode`, which is disabled by default.

It should be set to at least `prefer`, and also some of the other `server_tls_*` parameters might be needed to, depending on the TLS configuration at the other end.

See https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html#tls-settings for all the details.

Comment: thats it, it's worth mentioning that this parameter can be changed only by restarting pgbouncer